# How is the period called when used in business names to indicate a company division?

Tags: english, names, punctuation, proper-nouns

I'm occasionally seeing the full stop used in multiple languages in the names of various business entities to indicate their subdivisions, e.g. Acme.Logistics, Yandex.Mail, ...

Is there a specific term for this usage?

Comment: This is not a linguistics questikons. Please post it on the English Language Learners site. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie I spent a while thinking on where it is fit to ask about and decided that this is the place since it does not specifically pertain to English. If there is a more relevant place for it, I'd be glad to move it there.

Comment: Personally, I have never seen that.. If you type acme.logistics in google, it takes to their website. It is an internet thing. And: Yandex Mail (Russian: Яндекс Почта, tr. Yandeks Pochta; formerly stylised as Yandex.Mail) is a Russian free email service developed by Yandex. Wikipedia

Comment: "Acme" is the placeholder company name, I meant the general styling.

Comment: Ok, so put one up that actually uses a period like that. There is no reason not to. Since you claim you've been seeing it in multiple languages. I have never ever seen a company "division" with a period like that.  Otherwise, this is just a low quality question.

Comment: I don't think this is an English Language Learning question, no; it could fit here. But I'd like to see some more examples of this, since I'm not quite sure what you're asking about.

Comment: This is on topic.  It is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut, or pseudo-archaic spellings like "shoppe", which also occur in other languages.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer I was told by a participant in this forum that things that concern English specifically are off topic. Just saying. An umlaut is a diacritic which is completely usual as a question //There is no reason for the querent not to give us examples of this non-starting usage.

Comment: I don’t think this is a question about linguistics. The fact that periods are used in company names in various languages doesn’t change the fact that this appears to be a question asking for an _English_ term for such a usage – that makes it a question about an English word (though I’d say ELU rather than ELL, since I’d say most native speakers will draw a blank). Asking for the name of a specific _linguistics-related_ concept would be fair enough, but using a period as a fancy word separator in company names is marketing, not linguistics.